# How can I minimize validation intervals when changing the SQL in ADO NET Source Tasks

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis, sqlcommand

Part of an SSIS package is the data import from an external database via a SQL command embedded into an ADO.NET Source Data Flow Source. Whenever I make even the slightest adjustment to the query (such as changing a column name) it takes ages (in that case 1-2 hours) until the program has finished validation. The query itself returns around 30,000 rows with 20 columns each.

Is there any way to cut these long intervals or is this something I have to live with?

Comment: What is your query source? 1-2 hours sounds excessive, are you doing something extreme in your package and/or data flow? It's been my experience that long validation times are tied to either slow connectivity to a resource or the query itself is ... horrible. Not as an indictment of your ability to write a query, just that it's really hard to get the meta data about what columns and types are returned. In that case, I'd cheat. Point my ADO connection manager to an empty version of the source system. No data, no activity on the source should make for a faster validation.

Comment: Well, my query source is a PostgreSQL DB and my destination a table on an Microsoft SQL Server. So, the query was executed now and it took a whopping 7 hours to be finished. Below please find the progress protocol which looks very weird: [URL=http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3711/qkjcrkv9_png.htm][IMG]http://s1.directupload.net/images/140811/temp/qkjcrkv9.png[/IMG][/URL] I am not sure how your "cheat" works as I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually store the source queries in a table and the first part of my package would execute a select and store the query returned from the table in a package variable, which would then be used by the ADO.NET Source Data Flow. So In my package for the default value of the variable I usually have the query that is stored in the database along with a "where 1=2" at the end. Hence during design time it does execute the query but just returns the column metadata. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow, that sounds great but unfortunately I do not know what you mean. Is there maybe an online tutorial which is showing that procedure ideally with pictures? Sorry, but I am not really into all this.

Comment: Can anybody help me with the suggestion from TMNT2014?

Comment: Can you try using just a variable to store your SQL and setting the variable to the SQL command for the ADO .NET Source? For the SQL in the variable add to the where clause - AND 1=2 and see if that helps reduce the validation time. - Heres a link on how to set the SQL command as an variable.http://www.bidn.com/blogs/timmurphy/ssas/1127/dynamic-sql-command-variable-data-access-with-ado-net-source